# How do I modify the existing homepage for Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I'm wondering how I can modify the Tor Browser's default homepage to add/subtract HTML/JS/CSS. Is there a file somewhere I can edit to change this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source files for `about:tor` homepage are packed inside the Torbutton addon.

If you really need to modify the `about:tor` page, unpack `torbutton@torproject.org.xpi` file in `Data/Browser/profile.default/extensions` directory and look for the `chrome/content/aboutTor/aboutTor.xhtml` file.

Some helpful pointers:

- Mozilla knowledgebase: [Editing an add-on to change its compatibility](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_an_add-on_to_change_its_compatibility) (steps 3,4,5,6 are to be replaced by your edits)
- Check the page source online: [aboutTor.xhtml in Torbutton repository](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbutton.git/blob/HEAD:/src/chrome/content/aboutTor/aboutTor.xhtml).

Please note that Torbutton serves as a bridge between Tor network and Tor Browser. Modifying it may compromise your security.