# Change homepage/new tab page

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, startup

I know there have been posted some questions asking essentially the same. However, none of the fulfills my requirements.
I would simply like to modifiy TOR's homepage and new tab page to include a set of links to certain pages, in the same way Chrome does.

I know how to modify TOR's homepage, but the only alternative is to introduce a URL (well, I have managed to tell TOR to open all my Bookmarked pages, but that is neither what I want).

Is that possible? And, will this compromise the security [I have read something about modifying the `about:tor` file in the `Torbutton` `addon`, but a disclaimer says that could compromise theh security, plus I cannot find the `chrome/content/aboutTor/aboutTor.xhtml` file supposed to be in `Data/Browser/profile.default/extensions` (full answer [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/how-do-i-modify-the-existing-homepage-for-tor)]

**Important Remark.** I use Windows 10.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set your homepage to a `file://` URL so the homepage can be loaded from a text or HTML file on your local computer (rather than a URL on the internet). If it is plain text, the links won't be clickable.

When you open Tor, the new home page is used instead of the default Tor page.

Make a simple HTML file with your bookmarks in it and point the home page to there (e.g. `file://C:/Users/username/Desktop/bookmarks.html`). This does work in Tor on Windows 10. I would avoid using any remote resources (css, javascript) in that file and keep it all local if necessary.

As for modifying the new tab page, that is more of a problem. It seems that the aboutTor.xhtml and torbutton extension are more integrated into the browser now. The extension is still used but it is now contained in the browser build. Firefox [no longer supports](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1092024) a custom URL to be used for the new tab page. There are some extensions that can override this but some may not allow `file://` URLs and only support http/https. Adding more extensions into Tor could introduce risks, so use with caution.

If it is not too inconvenient, here's a workaround to the new tab page:

- Set the new tabs setting to "Blank Page" from `about:preferences` >> Home
- Customize your toolbar to add a "Home" button
- When opening a new tab page, click the Home button to load your custom bookmark file set above

This does introduce an extra click (to hit the home button after opening a new tab) but it may be a reasonable compromise for you.

You can get as creative as you want with the bookmarks page but here's a very simple starter template you can use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Tor Bookmarks</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bookmarks</h1>

    <h2>Category 1</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://example.com/">Example.com</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Category 2</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://example.net/">Example.net</a></li>
    </ul>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it as soon as possible. If it works, I'll accept it. But let me ask you some questions meanwhile. When you say "I would avoid using any remote source", what do you mean exactly? I mean, can I write arbitrary URL's on the HTML file? And in the template you provide, will the links be clickable? And yes, your soultion for the new tab page isn't perfect but I'd actually thought about it, and it's enough for the moment.

Comment: PS: I apologise for if my questions are trivial, but I have no idea about these things. I'm more used to classic browsers where everything is done interacting with the interface simply and no code is needed. The worst thing is this is just to get some privacy and avoid others tracking my VPN and things like that. It should not be so difficult, that is not fair.

Comment: The sample HTML I gave above is quite plain in appearance. While totally fine, it's understandable that you might want to make it look better by using [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS), images, or even adding functionality with Javascript. CSS, images, and Javascript are commonly loaded from a CDN or resource on the internet. If you want to include CSS to spice it up, I would *not* load them from the internet but instead store them locally on your computer (or even inline in the html file). Otherwise, you load remote resources every time the bookmark page loads.

Comment: ^^ Ran out of characters :- ) The urls in the example file are clickable, and that is totally fine; no security issues there. Here is a description of how to make [links](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) in HTML using the <a> tag. The example above is enough to satisfy your requirement of Tor's homepage including a set of (clickable) links to certain pages. While simple and boring it does work, but with a bit of CSS and styling it can look really cool too.

Comment: It works, thanks!! It's very simple, it's true, but it works, that's the most important thing for me. I'll think of improving it by using CSS (keeping everything local as you says), but yours is a perfect answer and you deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully changed the about:tor page by changing `chrome/torbutton/content/abouTor/aboutTor.xhtml` in `Browser/omni.ja`.

Comment: But how can I open that file?